# Linq to sql alias fails

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm working on a winforms project

and I have the following linq expressions

```
LinqQuery =
        from t in newContext?.TOURNAMENT_D
        from u in newContext.PLAYERS_LIST.Where(b => t.TD_ROWID == b.PL_TOURNAMENT_REFNO).DefaultIfEmpty()
        select new
        {
            t.TD_ROWID,
            t.TD_NAME,
            t.TD_DATE,
            startDate = t.TD_DATE,
            endDate = t.TD_DATE,
            u.PL_FULLNAME,
            u.PL_COUNTRY,
            u.PL_REENTRY
        };
```

and the following query is build after the linq query:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[TD_ROWID] AS [TD_ROWID], 
[Extent1].[TD_NAME] AS [TD_NAME], 
[Extent1].[TD_DATE] AS [TD_DATE], 
[Extent2].[PL_FULLNAME] AS [PL_FULLNAME], 
[Extent2].[PL_COUNTRY] AS [PL_COUNTRY], 
[Extent2].[PL_REENTRY] AS [PL_REENTRY]
FROM  [dbo].[TOURNAMENT_D] AS [Extent1]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[PLAYERS_LIST] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[TD_ROWID] = [Extent2].[PL_TOURNAMENT_REFNO]
```

I was expecting to see the dates with aliases am I missing something here?

is there a way that I can see the given aliases ?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

I was expecting the query to be like

```
[Extent1].[TD_DATE] AS startDate,
```

however I can still access that property within the IQueryable

Comment: Off-topic, but why do you use `newContext?`, with question mark? There shouldn't be any chance for the context to be `null`. On-topic, try to picture what it takes to translate a .Net expression to SQL. It would be more surprising if the range variable `t` *did* appear as SQL alias.

Comment: What aliases do you mean specifically?

Comment: yes you are right:)

Answer (score 1):

It's very important to realize that LINQ To SQL *is not* SQL itself. The query that is built is just the optimized query that LINQ To SQL runs on the database to pull the information it needs to pull the data into your C# object.

You should be able to call the following:

```
LinqQuery.startDate;
```

or

```
LinqQuery.endDate;
```

and those should hold the values that you defined in your select.

Please let me know if I can clarify.